# TPL Fire and Forget using a Separate Class

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to implement fire and forget functionality, using the Task Parallel Library.  With an inline call to `Task.Factory.StartNew`, everything works as expected.  However, I want to move the `Task.Factory.StartNew` call into a separate class so that I can add logging, error handling, etc, and potentially upgrade the code in the future as better threading classes, etc are added to the .NET Framework, without duplicating code.

Below is a unit test that I would expect to pass, but that does not.  I would appreciate help trying to figure out how to make this work.

```
[TestFixture]
public class ThreadingServiceFixture
{
    public static bool methodFired = false;

    [Test]
    public void CanFireAndForgetWithThreadingService()
    {
        try
        {
            var service = new ThreadingService();

            service.FireAndForget(() => methodFired = true);

            var endTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1);

            while(DateTime.Now < endTime)
            {
                //wait
            }

            Assert.IsTrue(methodFired == true);
        }
        finally
        {
            methodFired = false;
        }       
    }

}

public class ThreadingService
{
    public Task FireAndForget(Action action)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => action);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not executing the action, you're just returning it.

Try:

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => action());
```

Comment: Or, alternatively `StartNew(action)`.

Answer (score 2):

You did not invoke the action in the `ThreadingService`

The code should read something like

```
public class ThreadingService
{
    public Task FireAndForget(Action action)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => action.Invoke());
    }
}
```

Additional note: testing state with a public field is evil. Think about repeatability, maintenance, running tests in different order. You should move `bool methodFired` inside the test. I would also assume there is a better technique to test this (but I am not sure which one).

Answer (score 2):

If is "fire and forget" you don't need to return the `Task` from the `FireAndForget` method, because the caller could get that `Task` and cancel it (strictly speaking the caller would "remember" of the call).

If you want to invoke this method from many services that do not inherit from a common `ThreadingService` you can implement an extension method via  an interface.

```
public interface IFireAndForget 
{
     // no member needed.
}

public static class FireAndForgetExtensions 
{
    public static void FireAndForget(this IFireAndForget obj, Action action) 
    {
         // pass the action, not a new lambda
         Task.Factory.StartNew(action);
    }
}


// using
public class ThreadingService : IFireAndForget 
{

}
```

Also note the in your method you have to pass the `action` to the `StartNew` method insted of pass a lambda that return the `action` parameter.

Comment: Agreed, returning the task is a bad idea given the nature of the code.  I had added when trying to debug, but it certainly needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Testing threaded code is hard. 
Basing your tests on timing is a bad idea, they may become non-deterministic and you might observe erratic behavior on you build server. Imagine a tests that sometime passes and sometimes doesn't!

Your code has a bug, since you are not actually invoking the action.

But consider this variation:

```
[Test]
[TimeOut(5000)]
public void CanFireAndForgetWithThreadingService()
{
   var service = new ThreadingService();
   ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualRestEvent(bool); // I never remember what is the default...

   service.FireAndForget(() => mre.Set() /*will release the test asynchroneously*/);
   mre.WaitOne(); // blocks, will timeout if FireAndForget does not fire the action.
}
```

Yes, we are still using timing. But the test the timeout will happen only if the code breaks!
In all other scenarios, the test is absolutely predictable and takes a very short amount of time to execute, no waiting and praying for timing issues not to happen ;-)